# Kill OS if process is killed

Tags: kernel, process, crash, audit

I have a bespoke monitoring application I'm deploying on a linux cluster I wish to secure.

I would like the process **not** to be possible to `kill`.

That said, senior users need `root`.

I read that I can use kernel threads to achieve this. I would literally rather crash the OS than keep it up without this process.

Is this possible or even better is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Probably. Do senior users need **complete** and unfettered root access? If not, you could allow just the needed functions via `sudo` (or setuid programs, service daemons, ...).

Comment: cool idea, how do I restrict sudo to not be able to kill that process tho?

Comment: The other way around: you allow sudo access exactly for only those specific things they need to do. No sudo shell access.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani add as answer and I'mm mark as correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If senior users do not need complete and unfettered root access you could allow them to become root just to use the needed functions via sudo (or setuid programs, service daemons, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I guess better than killing the OS is to use a `/etc/init/yourservice.conf` script with `respawn` directive.

Comment: but can't that just be overridden by root?

Comment: Could be. I assumed it's rather against unintentional killing of that process, than against some malicious activity. In the latter case sure respawning will not suffice.

Comment: sorry, this is malicious actor

Comment: If you've a malicious actor then don't trust them with root.